# How can I check the difference between two C++ static library in Linux or Mac

Tags: c++, linux, macos

Now I have two C++ static libraries with the same name, for example `libA/libAbc.a` and `libB/libAbc.a`. The two libraries are different as their size is different. However, they are built with the same source codes but with different compilation and link configurations. My question is how I can obtain more details about their difference. Could I figure out the compilation options or link options that can lead to the difference? Thanks.

Comment: Using different flags on different compilation units can potentially make the code incompatible (as different flags can change the size and alignment of objects). It is usuall to add flags onto the name of a library to mark these differences. libABC.a => Optimized normal version.  libABCD.a => D suffix debug version.  etc...

Comment: "nm libA/libAbc.a" and "nm libB/libAbc.a" (and comparing those two commands' output using diff) could tell you if their symbol tables are different, and if so, what the differences are.

Answer (score 1):

Objdump -d - disassemble the lib.
nm - you can show table symbols.

Look at the option of the two commands to find out more.

Comment: This answer could be extended, maybe a reference to the documentation of the mentioned command, maybe a comparison with other tools - e.g. https://onlinedisassembler.com/static/home/index.html